# No warning about unused parameter in template function with gcc but with Clang

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang

I recently tested to build my code with clang instead of gcc. It fails, since I use *-Werror* because of an unused parameter in a template function. With gcc this does not happen.

Here is a small example:

```
template <typename REAL> int f(int a){return 42;}

int g(int a){return 42;}
```

Compiling it with clang give me the result I was hoping for:

```
$clang -c UnusedParam.cpp  -Wunused-parameter
>UnusedParam.cpp:1:36: warning: unused parameter 'a' [-Wunused-parameter]
> template <typename REAL> int f(int a){return 42;}
>                                   ^
>UnusedParam.cpp:3:11: warning: unused parameter 'a' [-Wunused-parameter]
> int g(int a){return 42;}
```

Gcc does only report the unused parameter in the second function.

```
$gcc -c UnusedParam.cpp  -Wunused-parameter
>UnusedParam.cpp:3:5: warning: unused parameter ‘a’ [-Wunused-parameter]
> int g(int a){return 42;}
```

Is there a way to enforce a similar behavior? I would like gcc to generate the unused parameter warning  as well.

**Compiler:**

- Clang: Version 3.3 (branches/release_33 183898)
- Gcc:   Version 4.8.1 20130909

Comment: I suggest you ask on a forum more geared toward GCC, and especially more frequented by the persons working on GCC, as it might actually be a bug.

Comment: What is a declaration, what a definition and what is both?

Comment: Possibly related: [error in unused template method](/q/17598699).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks @DieterLücking, your comment helped me a lot. Gcc seems to generate unused parameter warings only when the template function is **instantiated**.
Which seems to be a valid decision for this kind of warning, even so I would prefer
Clang's warning.

Here is a version where Gcc is complaining about the unused parameter:

```
template <typename REAL> int f(int a){return 42;}

int h(){return f<int>(3);}
```

Gcc Warning:

```
$ gcc -c UnusedParam.cpp  -Wunused-parameter
>UnusedParam.cpp: In instantiation of ‘int f(int) [with REAL = int]’:
>UnusedParam.cpp:4:24:   required from here
>UnusedParam.cpp:1:30: warning: unused parameter ‘a’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 template <typename REAL> int f(int a){return 42;}
```